# SwiftUI canvas preview compile error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a project where I am using Firebase's Firestore and Auth. When I create a SwiftUI view, the preview canvas doesn't work. I get the following error.

```
Compiling failed: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

failedToBuildDylib: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks-iphonesimulator'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___asan_alloca_poison", referenced from:
      +[GDTFLLUploader gzippedData:] in GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport(GDTFLLUploader.o)
  "___asan_allocas_unpoison", referenced from:
      +[GDTFLLUploader gzippedData:] in GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport(GDTFLLUploader.o)
  "___asan_handle_no_return", referenced from:
      -[FIRAuthCredential init] in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthCredential.o)
      -[FIRAuthCredential prepareVerifyAssertionRequest:] in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthCredential.o)
      -[FIREmailAuthProvider init] in FirebaseAuth(FIREmailAuthProvider.o)
      -[FIRCollectionReference initWithQuery:] in FirebaseFirestore(FIRCollectionReference.o)
```

This happens even with the most basic "Hello World" View, where I don't import anything related to Firebase.

Is there anything I can do about this, or can I simply not use the preview canvas in this entire project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix it by unchecking the "Address sanitizer" option from the scheme's diagnostics options.

Answer (score 60):

You can find a solution for it here by unchecking `Code Coverage` option

https://twitter.com/dannypier/status/1190312160557068293
[image]

Comment: This helped. But why should we do that? Looks like a bug in Xcode.

Comment: This is ridiculous, but it worked perfectly

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me: Disable Code Coverage for the scheme.

Answer found at: [CocoaPods Issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9275)

Comment: Yes this solution worked for me https://twitter.com/dannypier/status/1190312160557068293
by unchecking `Code Coverage` in `Test` section for scheme settings.

Answer (score 2):

Solved, at least for me. I received the following different errors (the beginning portion of the errors to avoid verbosity)

1.

```
no such module
```

2. 

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

----------------------------------------

LinkDylibError: Failed to build ImplementContributions.swift

Linking failed: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

3. Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
4. 

```
MessageSendFailure: Message send failure for update

==================================

|  RemoteHumanReadableError
|  
|  LoadingError: failed to load library at path
```

I tried dozens of solutions across 3 hours including messing with the Product Names because I was getting an error related to no such module, library search paths, framework paths, countless cleans, builds, reboots, xcrun simctl --set previews delete all and reboot, etc. But what finally appears to have worked was first turning ON and then turning OFF the code coverage which have moved locations from the checkbox in Test while editing your Scheme (CMD+<) to Test -> Test Plans (at the bottom of the view), tap the arrow to go into the Shared Settings -> Configuration -> Code Coverage.